# .NET Force method deferred execution

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, deferred-execution

Consider the following scenario

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>> CachedData;
```

where multiple threads access this variable via a method calling

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = CachedData.GetorAdd(key, HeavyDataLoadMethod())
```

where this method does some heavy weight operations to retrieve the data

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> HeavyDataLoadMethod()
{
        var data = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>(SomeLoad());
        foreach ( var item in OtherLoad())
           //Operations on data
        return data;
}
```

My problem here is that if I use`GetorAdd` the `HeavyDataLoadMethod`gets executed even if it is not needed.

I was wondering if there is some way to take advantage of deferred execution in this case and make the `HeavyDataLoadMethod`deferred so it is not executed until it is really needed.

(Yes, I know this is as simple as checking with a ContainsKey and forget about it, but I'm curious about this approach)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a delegate, instead of the direct function call:

Either pass in:

```
// notice removal of the `()` from the call to pass a delegate instead 
// of the result.
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = CachedData.GetorAdd(key, HeavyDataLoadMethod)
```

or

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dic = CachedData.GetorAdd(key, 
    (key) => HeavyDataLoadMethod())
```

[That way you pass in the pointer to the method, instead of the method results. Your heavy data load method must accept a parameter with the value of "key".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the method's overload, just what's needed